# Allow .net service port

Tags: .net, networking

I have a problem with a .net windows network service running on windows 10. I know there was a commandline tool to enable and allow services, because somthing changed with security since win 8 an higher .net frameworks. But I don't remember this builtin commandline tool. Do you remember? Firewall already disabled.

Comment: Why the downvote? Thx for downvoting without reason why to give a chance for improvement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the tool. It was netsh what I was looking for.

```
netsh add urlacl
```

Look here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx